# Why does my private array give me an inconsistent accessibility error using a public property to get it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties, encapsulation

Thanks for looking and thanks in advance for any advice you may have

I'd like to keep my array 'notes' private, as no other class should be tampering with it.

I do need other classes to read that data though, so thought that creating a property for it would be the correct way to go about encapsulating it.

However I get this error in Unitys console

```
Assets/testScripts/rhythmGameNotes.cs(22,23): error CS0053: Inconsistent
accessibility: property type `rhythmGameNotes.note[]' is less accessible      
than property `rhythmGameNotes.Notes'
```

Below is the source code (chopped up a bit)

```
private struct note
{
    public float y;
    public float noteDuration;
    public float noteSample;
    public GameObject go;
}

private note[] notes; // this should remain hidden from other classes

public note[] Notes
{
    get
    {
        return notes;
    }
}
```

Thanks again

Jim

Comment: change "private struct note" to "public struct note" or "internal struct note"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that you have is that your `note` struct is private and therefore only accessible to classes within the same file.

But as you are wishing to access this from the outside world people do not have access to the `note` Type meaning that when you are attempting to do:

```
public note[] Notes
{
    get
    {
       return notes;
    }
}
```

Your error is saying that the Type `note` is unable to be resolved publically. If you require people to access this struct from the property you will have to make the struct `public`:

```
public struct note
{
    public float y;
    public float noteDuration;
    public float noteSample;
    public GameObject go;
}
```

One further thing to note is that if you do not want any other class modifying your nice collection of notes then I would recommend that you change your property from returning an array to returning a `ReadOnlyCollection<note>`.

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<note> Notes
{
    get
    {
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<note>(notes);
    }
}
```

The reason for this as it says to classes using your object, this collection is not for modifying and is only for reading. I find this is more descriptive than a standard array and if I were using your class would tell me that there is no reason to make changes to the objects within the collection.

Answer (score 4):

The `Notes` field is public, returning an array of `note` objects. Meanwhile, the declaration of the `note` struct is private. This means that the "outside world" doesn't know anything about what the `Notes` field returns.

Changing the `notes` struct from private to public will solve the issue.

Comment: Beaten by 47 seconds :(

Comment: Thanks Steve & Deramko! Shouldn't the struct also be private though? As this also shouldn't be read tampered with by other classes?

Comment: You can't expose an array of them publicly if it's not also public. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve, without seeing the larger picture it's hard to say. Personally I'd be happy to expose a struct as they are value types and you don't run the risk of data changing from underneath you (everyone has their own copy). However if there is data in that struct you don't want exposed then create a different, public, struct e.g. PublicNote (a horrible name fwiw) and copy the data you want to expose into that version. Or make those properties private.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Make your struct public

```
public struct note
{
    public float y;
    public float noteDuration;
    public float noteSample;
    public GameObject go;
}
```